# Rails - Using SELECT in a WHERE clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to make a Rails model scope based on the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN tableB b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableB WHERE field = a.field)
```

I want to join rows of tableA with only one of tableB rows (the max one).
Is it possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 TableA
       .joins(:tableB)
       .where("a.id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tableB WHERE field = a.field)")
```

You'll need to have an [association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) between the two tables if you want the `joins` method works